# Selenium grid not working as expected when scaled horizontally using Autoscaling group

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, amazon-elb, aws-auto-scaling

I am running selenium grid as a docker container on EC2 instance which is controlled as part of Autoscaling group and the traffic is routed through load balancer. Test execution requests in this case. Everything is working fine when the desired count is 1 (no.of running ec2 instance) whenever it scales up to 2 or more. I start to see below error when I try to run any tests using Loadbalancer DNS name. ( however I can run the test cases just fine using private ip of the newly created instance)

**org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session [null] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.**

I did some troubleshooting with the help of AWS support by enabling access logs on ALB and it turns the request is getting forwarded successfully but there is no successful response.

It’s the same case if I try to run the selenium server directly On EC2 instead of using docker Containers.

Have you encountered the same problem? I would appreciate any assistance. Thanks in advance.